# Send SMS Twilio API and WorpressWordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, twilio, twilio-php

I am trying to implement an option on a website where a user can input their phone number and they will receive a text message. I am using Twilio and I am on WordPress.

I tried creating a simple plugin for this to work, but I'm stuck. I see the shortcode, but my form is not  displayed.

The plugin is designed like this in the WordPress plugin folder. I named this plugin twilio-sms then I have included in the project the Twilio php library and named it twilio-php :

My directory structure looks like this

Plugin folder : => twilio-sms

twilio-php (library) 
sms.php
form.php

In my project I also have two files: form.php which displays the form, and sms.php which should process the post request.

```
sms.php

<?php

if( !defined( 'MY_PATH' ) ) {
define( 'MY_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
}

require_once( MY_PATH . 'twilio-php/Twilio/autoload.php' );



// Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$sid = 'secret_id';
$token = 'secret_token';

// Use the REST API Client to make requests to the Twilio REST API
$client = new twilio-php\Twilio\Rest\Client;($sid, $token);

// Use the client to do fun stuff like send text messages!
$client->messages->create(
// the number you'd like to send the message to
$_POST['phone'],
array(
    // A Twilio phone number you purchased at twilio.com/console
    'from' => '+.... My Twilio Number',
    // the body of the text message you'd like to send
    'body' => "Hey " .$_POST[' name ']. "thiw is my message!"
)
); 

form.php

<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Twilio sms
Plugin URI: http://example.com
Description: Send sms using Twilio
Version: 1.0
Author: David
Author URI: http://example.com
*/


function html_form_code() {
echo '<form action="sms.php" method="post">';
echo '<label for="name">Name</label>';
echo '<input type="name" name="name" id="name" placeholder="your name"/><br/>';
echo '<label for="phone">Phone Number</label>';
echo '<input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="+14155551234"/><br/>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send SMS" />';
echo '</form>';
}


function sl_shortcode() {
ob_start();
html_form_code();
return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'contact_form', 'sl_shortcode' );

?>
```

Comment: If you replace the contents of the `sl_shortcode()` function with a simple text return (`return "Hello world!";`) does that get shown when you place your shortcode on a page?

Comment: Hi philnash, actually found a solution to implement sms texting from my website I am using a very simple plugn called 'joy of text lite' it works really well Thanks alot for your response

Comment: Glad that you got something working!